# How to get the value of a node in a binary form?

Tags: .net, xml, binary

I tried to do it with this code but I get an `ArgumentException` with "ms" in `byteArrayToImage` function.

`byteArrayToImage` working correctly with `byte[]` but I have trouble when I get node value.

XML node contains a binary code.

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}

static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    return bytes;
}

foreach (var binary in xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "binary"))
{

    if (item.Value == "cover.jpg") MessageBox.Show(item.Value.ToString());
    foreach (var binaryAttr in binary.Attributes())
    {
        if (binaryAttr.Value == "cover.jpg")
        {
            var s = GetBytes(binary.Value);

            byteArrayToImage(s);


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "contains a binary code". Usually, binary data in XML is stored in Base64... whereas you're converting plain character data in a way which almost certainly wouldn't work in XML.

I suspect you can remove your `GetBytes` method and just use

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(binary.Value);
```

Comment: My node contains code like <binary> fhdfkhgdf7gy34th3 </ binary>. There is stored image.
Thank you!